# SQL - Selection within Case when

Tags: sum, case-when, multiple-conditions

I have a code that yields the desired output for a "moving" universe in which it looks at each period and gives me the information.I would like to have another query that yields the same output but for a different selection, a "current" universe.

A current universe would make the sums just as they do now but just for companies who meet the criteria at the latest date in the database.

Right now the code yields EBIT/Sales 2015 for companies that had Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 2015 and so on but I would rather want it to yield EBIT/Sales 2015 for Companies that has Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 currently (latest date_month in Market_Cap)

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

I've tried to insert another criteria in the sum(case when ... then) syntax as "And c.company_id in(Select company_id from Market_cap where Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 and Date = '2017-06-30)) but I get error:

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Code now:

```
 select m.date_month     
     ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2015 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 AND mm.Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2015 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 AND mm.Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 then s.Sales end) as 'EBIT/Sales 2015'  
     ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2016 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 AND mm.Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2016 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 AND mm.Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 then s.Sales end) as 'EBIT/Sales 2016'  
     ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2017 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 AND mm.Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2017 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 AND mm.Market_Cap between 0 and 10000 then s.Sales end) as 'EBIT/Sales 2017'  
 from  EBIT   as n  
     inner join  Sales   as s on  s.company_id = n.company_id  
                             and s.date_month_id = n.date_month_id  
                             and s.date_year_id = n.date_year_id  
     inner join date_year as y on y.date_year_id = n.date_year_id  
     inner join date_month as m on m.date_month_id = n.date_month_id 
     inner join Market_Cap as mm on mm.Date_Month_Id = n.Date_Month_Id
                             and mm.Company_Id = n.Company_Id
     inner join Company as c on c.Company_Id = n.Company_Id
 where y.date_year between   2015  and   2017     
     and n.EBIT<> 0  
     and s.Sales<> 0 
 group by m.date_month;
```

Correct output:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code you included here was the selection code, not the code that actually filters based on market cap. Wouldn't you want to change these lines:

```
inner join Market_Cap as mm on mm.Date_Month_Id = n.Date_Month_Id
                         and mm.Company_Id = n.Company_Id
```

to compare `mm.Date_Month_Id` to something like `max(Date_Month_Id)`?

Comment: Thank you, I got to caught up in the Sum(Case when...Then) syntax that I forgot about the principles of SQL ... it works now

Answer (score 0):

Correct Query (I think):

```
 select m.date_month     
     ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2015 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2015 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 then s.Sales end) as 'EBIT/Sales 2015'  
     ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2016 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2016 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 then s.Sales end) as 'EBIT/Sales 2016'  
     ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2017 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2017 AND c.Country_Id in (4,5,6) AND c.factSet_Level1_Id between 1 and 100 then s.Sales end) as 'EBIT/Sales 2017'  
 from  EBIT   as n  
     inner join  Sales   as s on  s.company_id = n.company_id  
                             and s.date_month_id = n.date_month_id  
                             and s.date_year_id = n.date_year_id  
     inner join date_year as y on y.date_year_id = n.date_year_id  
     inner join date_month as m on m.date_month_id = n.date_month_id 
     inner join Market_Cap as mm on mm.Date_Month_Id = n.Date_Month_Id
                             and mm.Company_Id = n.Company_Id
     inner join Company as c on c.Company_Id = n.Company_Id
 where y.date_year between   2015  and   2017 and c.Company_Id in (Select Company_Id from Market_Cap Where Market_Cap between 0 and 1000) 
     and n.EBIT<> 0  
     and s.Sales<> 0 
 group by m.date_month
 order by m.Date_Month asc;
```